# configurable products attributes not showing in layered navigation

Tags: attributes, configurable-product, layered-navigation

From this page http://boxchilli.co/s2as/kiteboard/kitesurfing/harnesses.html you should be able to see under the `Filter By` There should be `Size` however this doesn't show from the configurable products on the page

There is a part on the website were this does work http://boxchilli.co/s2as/gopro.html you can see the configurable product and the correct filters.

Whole site has been reindexed, Categories have been set to Anchor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attribute has been set so that it's available in Layered Navigation, right? In Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes each attribute has a frontend properties section.  I'd have put this as a comment, but I had a screenshot so thought it might be helpful;

[image]

**Edit**

There is a difference between the two and you can see it when you add both products to cart (ie a harness and a test product).  With a harness the option is lower case, with the test product it is capitalised.  So maybe the harnesses are simple products with custom options (which can't be filtered using layered navigation) and the test product is a configurable?

**Answer**

Answer from comments -> The two products had different attributes.

[image]

Comment: That field as been selected for the attribute.

Comment: Have updated the answer Lee :)

Comment: Your answer was close. Were we have a large amount of people working on the product the size for the harness is different attribute than the size used for the test product. Thanks for helping me to notice this

Comment: Ah, you know I was going to add that as another alternative.  Excellent, glad it got you on the right track and sorted it!